# Creating a dual Mac/Win Autorun CD

Tags: windows, macos, installation

How do I create a CD that opens a "Drag this icon to the Application folder to install" on the Mac and autoruns an installer on Windows?

Comment: I agree with BobbyShaftoe, it's a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jordan Brough has a really good write-up on his blog about this:

http://jordan.broughs.net/archives/2008/03/creating-cross-platform-windows-and-mac-installer-cds

For what it's worth, this was the first result returned from a fairly simple google search...

Comment: Just curious, what search term did you use to find the blog?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [hdiutil](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html)

eg.

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o [output-file] [input-folder] -iso -hfs -hide-iso [mac-only-file] -hide-hfs [windows-only-files]
```

What you will want to do is hide the windows specific files from the HFS partition and hide the Mac only files from the ISO.

Then you would use an autorun file as your normally would on Windows.

On the Mac side there are many applications you can buy for creating a Finder window that looks a certain way but all these changes can be made within finder.  You then will need to copy the DS_Store file to the CD and finder will automatically apply any changes that you have made.

Also using -hfs-openfolder will cause it to open automatically when inserted on the mac.

Comment: Remark for those who may still be wondering: -hide-iso and -hide-hfs do not simply hide the given files/folders from the view but don't expose them to a particular system at all making them inaccessible on that platform.