# Opening Flash file from USB automatically on Win/Mac

Tags: macos, flash, usb, autorun

I need to have a flash file be opened and viewed from a USB automatically on both Win and Mac.

I read about various solutions depending on the format of the flash output:

- *autorun.inf* if Flash published as exe(Win)/app(Mac)) which seems to be working only on Win;
- *html embedding* if Flash is published as swf, but this turns into a problem of launching html file.

What is the best known practice/solution?

Answer (score 2):

For the PC, you can use an autorun script. On the Mac, there is no such feature (thankfully). What you can do on the Mac is have the Mac partition open, and using a background image, display instructions to "click here to start", or whatever other verbiage you desire, pointing to your Flash Projector file.

Answer (score 1):

will [this](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/133/tn_13374.html) help ?

Comment: Unfortunately, autorun does not work on Mac as discussed in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452289/creating-a-dual-mac-win-autorun-cd]. The workaround is based on CD image which is to my knowledge is not applicable to USBs.

Comment: USB devices can announce themselves as removable CD drives. If the bits look right, the Mac won't know that they came from Flash memory.

Comment: The links is dead, bu t @MSalters can you explain how to implement such a thing?