# Create Hybrid Mac and Windows ISO with custom main folder settings

Tags: macos, terminal, iso, autorun, hybrid

I'm trying to create an hybrid CD able to autorun on Windows machines and auto-open the main folder with a custom background on Mac OSX.
The CD has to start an application in flash showing also some PDF files.

Here the scheme of the CD files and folders:

```
application.exe <-- the app for windows
autorun.inf <-- the autorun file for windows
application.app <-- the app for mac osx
/documents <-- the folder which contains the PDF files for both the applications
/background <-- the folder which contains the background image for Mac OSX
```

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452289/creating-a-dual-mac-win-autorun-cd) I was able to set a background folder image for mac and create the first hybrid ISO with this command:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o [image.iso] [my_project_folder] -iso -hfs -hide-iso [file to hide on windows] -hide-hfs [file to hide on mac]
```

Unfortunately with this command I wasn't able to hide more than one file; I need at least 2 (.exe and .inf) for mac.
And even if the background results correctly set to my original folder 
 when I open the ISO it seems to lost it and other settings like the window and icons dimensions.

---

**Update:**

The correct syntax for hdiutil command to hide multiple files is the following:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o image.iso source_folder -iso -hfs -hide-iso cd_folder/application.app -hide-hfs "{cd_folder/application.exe,cd_folder/autorun.inf}"
```

Unfortunately the folder background image, window dimensions and icon positioning still desappear in the iso file.
It is possible to re-set them again but every time the iso is ejected and re-mounted OSX seems to forget my preferences...

---

**Solution:**

After several attempts I have finally found the cause:
 the read and write mount command `hdiutil attach -readwrite myCD.iso` does't work on Mountain Lion 
Therefore the OS doesn't save / remember my preferences.
I have noticed this behaviour also trying to create the hybrid image with `Toast`; when I have tried to mount `myCD.toast` and change the icon position it wasn't allowed (and I realized the problem).

Hence I replicate the process with my old Snow Leopard and everything worked perfectly! 
 Also creating the hybrid CD with Toast is really easier and fully customizable.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is make a read-write disk image, set up background image, icon size, and so on, unmount the image, and make sure it restores properly on remount.  To get a designated folder to open when the image mounts, I use the `bless` command.  Once the read-write image works as I want, I make the hybrid image using the read-write image as the source.  I've made a [set of AppleScript programs](http://www.jwwalker.com/pages/hybrid-cd.html) to simplify the process.

Comment: the real problem seems to be the mount command under Mountain Lion; it doesn't recognize -readwrite option. Under Snow Leopard everything works perfectly.